# WSO2 ESB TryIt tool doesn't show cyrillic

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have a WSO2 Data server services, which I map through WSO2 ESB. The Data Server Service returns some cyrillic fields (utf-8 encoding).

When I use the "tryIt" feature in the ESB, the service works just fine, but the response's encoding is broken. I am sure the problem is **not** in the encoding of the database.

Is that a bug and most important is the problem only with the "tryIt" feature?

[image]

P.S. Sorry for the small picture, but you can still see the "???? ????" symbols which should be cyrillic letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone needs this I've found out that the problem is in the tryIt tool. When I call the service from SOAP UI or from a generated stub the text encoding is ok.